# Django and React authentication with Axios failing

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, session, axios

I am building a web app with React and Django (frontend and backend resp.) and I am struggling to do user authentication. The urls in Django in my setup are basic, I will commit them for now.

The views should be straightforward (feel free to suggest a more idiomatic approach as I am struggling with getting the right request response flow) basically, you can get a user with /users/int:id/ which returns either a private or public user object depending on whether the id is also the id of the authenticated user, login sends the id of the current user when successful.

The issue I have is that login on it's own works just fine, though, when I refresh the page, react seems to have forgotten that the user was logged, it would be really annoying to ask the user to log in every time the page reloads. Therefor I made the authenticate view (and url users/authenticate/) which is supposed to return the private user object based on the session id. It is at this stage that things go wrong, the view does not recognise the user as authenticated (i.e., is_authenticated would fail).

Some of the react: Home.js

```
export const Home = () => {

  let [user, setUser] = useUserContext()

  client.post('/users/authenticate/')
    .then(res => setUser(res.data))
    .catch(err => { console.log(err) })

  function login(email, password) {
    client.post('/users/login/', {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    })
      .then(res => client.get(`/users/${res.data}/`))
      .then(res => setUser(res.data))
      .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
  }
  function register(details) {
    console.log(details)
  }

  return(
    <div id='home'>
      <div id='highlights'>
        <h2>HIGHLIGHTS</h2>
      </div>
      { !user && <Login onSubmit={ login }/> }
      { user && <Feed></Feed> }
      { !user && <SignUp onSubmit={ register }/> }
    </div>
  )
}
```

App.js

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

export const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
})
```

The Django views are set up as follows (again feel free to suggest more idiomatic approaches):

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.http import Http404
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from . import serializers as srs
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes, permission_classes
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated


# Create your views here.
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def login(request):
  email = request.data['email']
  password = request.data['password']
  if not User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
    return Http404('account does not exist')
  user = User.objects.get(email=email)
  id = user.id
  user = auth.authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
  if user is not None:
    auth.login(request, user)
    return Response(id)
  else:
    raise PermissionDenied('wrong password')

@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def authenticate(request):
  return Response(srs.User(request.user).data)


@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def logout(request):
  auth.logout(request)
  return Response()

@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def get_user(request, id):
  user = User.objects.get(id=id)
  if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.id == id:
    return Response(srs.User(user).data)
  else:
    return Response(srs.PublicUser(user).data)
```

And in settings I have (a part of the file)

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
    "corsheaders",
    "users",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
  "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
  "http://localhost:3000",
]
#CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
  "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
  "http://localhost:3000",
]
#DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES = [
#  'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
#  'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
#]

#CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'XSRF-TOKEN'
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
#CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_XSRF_TOKEN'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    #'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    #    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    #),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

The strange thing is that everything works fine when connect to the backend directly (for example http://localhost:8000/users/login/ and http://localhost:8000/users/authenticate/ and manually post using Django rest frameworks ui). So I suppose I just have some wrong settings in my frontend code?

Thanks!

Comment: After some inspection (using inspect) It seems that my requests from the native Django rest framework site are sending cookies along with the request, but in my react code, the axios requests are not...